# Printer configurations on Linux: Providing privilege to normal users

Tags: linux, centos, lpr

I am on a **CentOS** machine. Everything is working fine, I can configure the printer with the GUI `System->Administration->Printing`. It asks for root password and then I can make the configurations. But I couldnt find a way I could let the normal user on the system to configure printer for himself.

1. So isnt it possible for a normal user to configure printers?
2. So what would be the best practice to achieve this? With sudo or some other configurations.

**Update:** I wonder why it doesnt work with `sudo` either or am I missing something?

I tried to give privilege to the user *beginer* to run the command `/usr/bin/system-config-printer` . I tried with `visudo`

```
beginer ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/system-config-printer
```

But on the terminal when *beginer* runs `sudo /usr/bin/system-config-printer` after giving the password this error is thrown.

```
Sorry, user beginer is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/system-config-printer' as root on HOST.DOMAINNAME .
```